# Forge / Nginx DO WWW to non-WWW redirect issue

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I just transferred a site to a DO server provisioned by Forge. I installed an SSL certificate and noticed that navigating to https://www.example.com results in a Server Not Found error, while http://example.com returns 200. I attempted to force non-WWW in the Nginx config file but cannot seem to make anything work. I also restarted Nginx after every attempt.

Here is my current Nginx config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name .example.com;
root /home/forge/default/current/public;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default/56210/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default/56210/server.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

The server was set up with the default site - default, rather than example.com. I realized this after launching the site to production and installing the SSL cert, I am trying to avoid any downtime by trying to change this after the fact. I am not sure if the site being called default makes any difference here, but it's key to note.

So, https:// or http://example.com works fine. www.example.com returns a Server Not Found error on all browsers I've tested. I also noticed that there is a www.default file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, I tried changing it to the following and restarting nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://example.com/$request_uri;
}
```

Still receiving Server Not Found no matter what. Here is the error on Chrome:

The server at www.example.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I just needed to take a break. After I finished off my lunch, it occurred to me that Chrome was giving me the answer all along - it was a DNS issue. I added an A record for www pointing to my IP address on Digital Ocean, problem solved.

I believe www is missing by default on DO servers provisioned by Laravel Forge.